# Getting URL of the media to play from media server with Cling

Tags: android, upnp

I'm working on the example upnpBrowser of Cling upnp stack on android and I browse the content of the merdia server and i can display the list of media in every folder and now i want to extract the URL of the video to play it on a player, but I'm blocked how to extract that URL !!!

```
UDN serverUdn = ((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).server_udn;
//Device server = ((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).server;
Device server = upnpService.getRegistry().getDevice(serverUdn, true);
listAdapter.clear();
if(server == null)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "pbm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    if(server.findService(new UDAServiceType("ContentDirectory")) == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "pbm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(new Browse(server.findService(new UDAServiceType("ContentDirectory")),id, BrowseFlag.DIRECT_CHILDREN)
    {
        @Override
        public void received(ActionInvocation actionInvocation, DIDLContent didl) {
            final List<Item> items = didl.getItems();
            String st=didl.getItems().get(0).getFirstResource().getValue();
```

Comment: I suppose your `String st` is not giving you the URL. What is the `id` you are providing as parameter to `Browse()` action? Does that container id really have media URLs in it? Every container is not required to hold media directly!

Comment: yes it didn't give anything, but the weird thing is that if I remove this line:
    String st=didl.getItems().get(0).getFirstResource().getValue();
the code executes and displays files and media server and when I put it, displays nothing!

Comment: Show the code which "executes and displays files" when you remove your line `String st`. Make sure that object id `id` provided to `Browse()` really holds media items.

Comment: this is the browseserver class, it displays folders and files in the media server

Answer (score 1):

```
public void browseServer(final String id)
{

    if(((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).server_udn == null)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Bad")
        .setMessage("pas de serveur sélectionné, allez à la section LAN et cliquez sur Parcourir pour sélectionner le serveur!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // Some stuff to do when cancel got clicked
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
    else
    {
        UDN serverUdn = ((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).server_udn;
        //Device server = ((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).server;
        Device server = upnpService.getRegistry().getDevice(serverUdn, true);
        listAdapter.clear();
        if(server == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "désolé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            if(server.findService(new UDAServiceType("ContentDirectory")) == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "pbm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(new Browse(server.findService(new UDAServiceType("ContentDirectory")),id, BrowseFlag.DIRECT_CHILDREN)
            {

                @Override
                public void received(ActionInvocation actionInvocation, DIDLContent didl) {

                    final List<Item> items = didl.getItems();

                    //String st = items.getImportUri();
                    //String st=didl.getItems().get(0).getFirstResource().getValue(); 
                    //Log.d("URL IS",st); 
                    //Item item = didl.getItems().get(0);
                    //Item item = didl.getItems().get(0); 
                    //String url = item.getFirstResource().getValue();

                     //System.out.println(" this is the url of item" +item.getTitle()); 
                    // System.out.println(" this is the url of the media");

                     //System.out.println(url);

                    /*final DIDLContent b = didl;
                    String str1 = "bieda";
                    try
                    {
                        str1 = parser.generate(b);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        str1 = "smuta";
                    }
                    final String str=str1;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {

                            adb.setTitle("XML").setMessage(str).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
                                }
                            }).show();

                        }
                    });*/

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run()
                        {
                            listAdapter.insert(new ServerContentContainer(s.peek()), 0);
                        }
                    });

                    final List<Container> containers = didl.getContainers();

                    for(final Container c: containers)
                    {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run()
                            {
                                int pos = listAdapter.getPosition(new ServerContentContainer(c));
                                if(pos >= 0)
                                {
                                    listAdapter.remove(new ServerContentContainer(c));
                                    listAdapter.insert(new ServerContentContainer(c), pos);
                                    System.out.println("eulooooooooo");
                                }
                                else
                                    listAdapter.add(new ServerContentContainer(c));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    for(final Item i: items)
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run()
                            {
                                int pos = listAdapter.getPosition(new ServerContentItem(i));
                                if(pos >= 0)
                                {
                                    listAdapter.remove(new ServerContentItem(i));
                                    listAdapter.insert(new ServerContentItem(i), pos);
                                }
                                else
                                    listAdapter.add(new ServerContentItem(i));
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void updateStatus(Status arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(ActionInvocation arg0, UpnpResponse arg1,
                        String arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the class ServerContentItem :

```
protected class ServerContentItem extends ServerContent
    {
        private Item i;

        public Item getItem()
        {
            return i;
        }

        ServerContentItem(Item i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public void select()
        {
            if(((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).renderer_udn != null)
            {
                Device renderer = upnpService.getRegistry().getDevice(((UpnpControlApplication)getApplicationContext()).renderer_udn, false);
                final Service service = renderer.findService(new UDAServiceType("AVTransport"));
                upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(new SetAVTransportURI(service, i.getFirstResource().getValue()){
                    @Override
                    public void failure(ActionInvocation invocation, UpnpResponse operation, String defaultMsg) {
                        adb.setTitle("Bad").setMessage("No!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
                            }
                        }).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(ActionInvocation invocation)
                    {
                        upnpService.getControlPoint().execute(new Play(service){
                            @Override
                            public void failure(ActionInvocation invocation, UpnpResponse operation, String defaultMsg) {
                                adb.setTitle("Bad").setMessage("Non réussi!")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",new OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                        // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked
                                    }
                                }).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
            else
            {
                adb.setTitle("Bad")
                .setMessage("selection ! need a media player ")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // Some stuff to do when ok got clicked         
                        Log.e("bla","blablaa");


                        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(BrowseServerActivity.this, Newactivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return i.getTitle();
        }

        @Override 
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if(this == o)
                return true;
            if(getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;
            return i.equals(((ServerContentItem)o).i);
        }
    }
```

I hope that's the code is clear. thx

Comment: Ok so you are really using `Item.getFirstResource().getValue()`. That should work. But in the original code, you are iterating **all** items. In your new code, you are trying to use only the **first** item `didl.getItems().get(0)`. Not all items are required to have a resource. It may also be a container.

Comment: I just tested the first value, but It's the same problem, when I try to get the first item from all items, so i don't know where's the proble.more when I try as I said to extract the values ​​of the items, the application stopped and shows no view, I do not know if you understood my problem. thank you

Comment: I am afraid i don't understand anymore. The problem may be that you are creating yet another runOnMainThread which is perhaps doing incorrect things. I am not that much into Android. I recommend placing a lot of `Log`-ing in your code and seeing where the URL gets lost. Your code is roughly UPnP-correct, doing the same thing as the original `ServerContentItem` which you claim is working right.

Comment: What happens if there is no AVtransport service avaialable in the device? Again to clarify, are you looking up the AVTransport in the server right? and when you call the play() method the current device starts playing the media right?

Answer (score -1):

The Cling Ressource class contains a **URI** field , get it and try .
[Res CLING Support 1.0.5 API](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/support/apidocs/org/teleal/cling/support/model/Res.html)

Comment: That is reflection of `res@importUri` - very specialized and related to **uploading**, not downloading the media from server, which is what OP is asking for.